# Adjoint of numpy.gradient

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on an optimization problem whose scalar cost function is of the form,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime

def cost(x_1d):
    N = int(x_1d.size**0.5)
    x_2d = x_1d.reshape((N,N))
    gy, gx = np.gradient(x_2d)
    
    cost = (gy*gy).sum()
```

I need to be able to compute the gradient of this function.  The squaring operation means it looks something like,

```
def cost_and_grad(x_1d):
    N = int(x_1d.size**0.5)
    x_2d = x_1d.reshape((N,N))
    gy, gx = np.gradient(x_2d)
    
    cost = gy*gy.sum()
    costbar = gy
    gybar = costbar*gy # eq. 4.49 (real-valued, no need for conj)
    # backpropagation through np.gradient?
```

I am using the notation of [table 1, pg 104 of this thesis](https://urresearch.rochester.edu/institutionalPublicationPublicView.action?institutionalItemVersionId=28820).

If we re-write out own gradient, we end up with something like this,

```
class SpatialGradient2D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = None
    
    def forward(self, A):
        self.A = A
        shp = A.shape
        # slcy and slcx are where we insert into out
        self.slcy = slice(1, shp[0]-1) # slice is end-inclusive
        self.slcx = slice(1, shp[1]-1)
        
        # left and right samples along y axis (dim0)
        self.slcyleft = slice(0, shp[0]-2)
        self.slcyright = slice(2, shp[0])
        
        # along x axis
        self.slcxleft = slice(0, shp[1]-2)
        self.slcxright = slice(2, shp[1])
        
        outx = np.zeros_like(A)
        outy = np.zeros_like(A)
        
        # f'(x) ~= [f(x+eps) - f(x-eps)]/2eps
        # left (-eps) and right (+eps) samples for X
        # call it (b-a)/2
        
        self.a = A[self.slcy, self.slcxleft]
        self.b = A[self.slcy, self.slcxright]
        
        # for Y
        # call it (d-c)/2
        self.c = A[self.slcyleft, self.slcx]
        self.d = A[self.slcyright, self.slcx]
        
        outx[self.slcy, self.slcx] = (self.b-self.a)/2  # assume dx=1; 2=2*dx
        outy[self.slcy, self.slcx] = (self.d-self.c)/2  # assume dx=1
        
        return outy, outx

    def reverse(self, protograd):
        # just deal with the y part
        # out = (d-c)/2
        step1 = protograd / 2
        
        # now grad of d and c
        # z = x+y
        # xbar = zbar
        # ybar = zbar
        # 
        # so dbar = step1
        #    cbar = -step1
        dbar = step1
        cbar = -step1
        # now need to propagate d and c to grad
        # backprop of index is assignment
        # in this case, sum-assign
        out = np.zeros_like(self.A)
        out[self.slcyleft,self.slcx] += cbar[self.slcyleft,self.slcx]
        out[self.slcyright,self.slcx] += dbar[self.slcyright,self.slcx]
        return out
```

This is a little different in computation to numpy gradient, particularly for the edge-most samples of the array; let's start by getting things right in the center.

To keep things somewhat simple, sample data:

```
x = y = np.arange(-4, 5, 1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
apx = (xx > -3) & (xx < 3)
apy = (yy > -3) & (yy < 3)
ap = (apx&apy).astype(float) # a rectangle
```

The expected answer should be inline with approx_fprime:

```
>>> approx_fprime(ap.ravel(), cost).reshape(xx.shape)
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

At the moment I am getting zero for the adjoint, which can't be right...